# Get all pages including sub-pages via Bigcommerce API

Tags: bigcommerce

I am using the https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/{storeID}/v2/pages endpoint to get all pages but it does not return the sub-pages. Is there a separate endpoint to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

There is a limit for the number of page responses so i was not getting all pages. I had to increase the limit parameter and then was able to see all pages including sub-pages

Comment: try to include links to documentation, and the values used to help others, e.g. `?limit=250` and https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/marketing/store-content-api/pages/getallpages